# Convert character to factor matching part of string

Tags: r, character, matching

I would like to convert a character variable into a factor matching part of string. For example I have this kind of output

```
c("09:32", "09:55" ,"09:51", "09:52", "08:36", "08:44", "08:21" ,"08:00")
```

and I want to create a factor with two levels splitting times for hours. Could you help me?

Comment: In which language, my friend?

Comment: Sorry :) I'm using R

Comment: Sorry, not my thing ;) But I fixed the tags for you..

Comment: Do you want to retain this same output while setting levels as hours?

Comment: No. I want to convert a character vector of times (larger than my example) into a factor but grouped by hours. In other words I want to convert this variable in a factor with 24 level (one for hour). My idea is to select the first two letters of every string to group strings into a factor. Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: If your string called `x` just do `factor(substring(x, 1, 2))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I think the approach in your comment is superior to the current answer. Please consider posting it as an answer. :)

Comment: @AlexA. You are welcome to post this, I don't mind. You also don't need to mention me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Done, but I couldn't _not_ mention you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished even more simply than in the other answer. If `x` is your vector of strings, just do this:

```
factor(substring(x, 1, 2))
```

This creates a factor variable where the levels are the first two characters in `x`.

P.S. Thanks to David Arenburg for posting this in a comment and giving me permission to post as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("09:32", "09:55", "09:51")
hour <- factor(as.numeric(substring(x, 1, 2)), levels = c(8, 9))
```

Comment: Yes! It work! You have to convert in numeric to solve this but if you want to match first two letters and not first two numbers?